# Python multiprocessing processing name of processes

Tags: python

I'm trying to create few processes and run them through the Python multiprocessing module,
I used the below code to determine the process name of each process that's being submitted but I noticed all the process are running on the same processor atleast the name looks same.

When do the jobs start running on the other processors? 
How do I identify the proceesor name its running?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import platform

def process1():
    print 'process_1 processor =',platform.processor() 

def process2():
    print 'process_2 processor =',platform.processor()

def main():
    print 'Main processor =',platform.processor()
    processlist = []
    p1 = Process(target = process1)
    p1.start()
    processlist.append(p1)

    p2 = Process(target = process2)
    p2.start()
    processlist.append(p2)

    for i in processlist:
        i.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

OUtput
Main processor = Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
process_2 processor = Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
process_1 processor = Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to determine CPU name on which process running with this library, but you can determine CPU CORE numbers related to process.

```
import psutil,os
self_process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
self_process.get_cpu_affinity()
# [0,1] - i have 2 core cpu and process can load both cores
self_process.set_cpu_affinity([1])
# now this process can load only one core #1
```

You can get pids in main process and set CPU cores to run after spawning.
Don`t know can about multi CPU behavior...